# Need to find least value of an algebraic expression without helper constraints.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to solve this problem:

Given $a>b>0$, find the least value of $a + \frac {1}{b(a-b)}$

Initially I was confused and things got better when I re-wrote $a + \frac {1}{b(a-b)}$ as $(a-b) + b + \frac {1}{b(a-b)}$

Then, the given equation assumed a friendlier form $x + y + \frac{1}{xy} $

While further searching this community, I found a very similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756702/if-a2b2-1-where-a-b0-then-find-the-minimum-value-of-ab1-overab). This problem was finding the minimum value of $a + b + \frac{1}{ab}$. But there was a constraint helping this case: $a^2+b^2=1$. They established $(2+\sqrt2)$ as the minimum value.

I followed similar lines (AM>GM inequality) and ended up with a complex expression that looked like $2b(a-b) \le a^2+2b^2-2ab$ as there was no helper constraints.

I wonder (for the second time today) whether the problem statement is incomplete or a minimum value can be reached without constraints such as $a^2+b^2=1$.

Could you please help me out here?

Note: I know the Calculus way of solving this problem. But I am supposed to use algebra (inequalities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you gave us the hint by yourself:$$a+\frac{1}{b(a-b)}=a-b+b+\frac{1}{b(a-b)}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{(a-b)b}{b(a-b)}}=3$$ by AM-GM generated with no Mathematica. The equal sign holds for $a=2,b=1$

Comment: Wow. Thank you. It was so simple. I began well and got distracted by another problem which had a constraint.

Comment: yes i agree you can come in my Mathcircle in Leipzig, you are wellcome

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can I come ?

Comment: do you have a question? right now

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, I'd like to pay a visit to the Mathcircle in Leipzig

Comment: hm it is a Long way from USA to Leipzig, but you are welcome

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm in France, und ich spreche fliessend Deutsch

Comment: Ja gut aber es ist auch eine weite Reise, wo genau wohnst Du denn?